# System Properties are not resolved in JBOSS EAP 7.0

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

I am trying to migrate from jboss-eap-6.2 to jboss-eap-7.0. I have a few system properties in standalone.xml that I've used in jboss-eap-6.2 but the same properties doesn't get resolved in eap 7.0.

```
 <system-properties>
        <property name="LOGIN_URL" value="https://localhost:8543/test/test.jsp"/>
       ...
       ...
       ...
 </system-properties>
```

I'm adding these properties under the  tag only. Still it doesn't get resolved during run time when my code tries to pick it up.

Comment: How are you adding the system properties?

Comment: In standalone.xml file of jboss under the <extensions> tag

Comment: Is the server stopped when you add the property? I just tried adding one and tried reading it from a servlet with no issues.

Comment: which version of jboss? cause the same thing worked for me in jboss eap 6.2 and is not working in jboss eap 7.0

Comment: I tried EAP 7.0. No issues for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out why the system properties were not accessible through the application! Gotta set

```
<spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
```

tag's value to true. It is by default set to false. It will be under the sub system `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">`

Changing this to true worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Check with following CLI command if system property get resolved or not.

`/system-property=LOGIN_URL:read-attribute(name=value)`

Comment: It's not resolved. thats the issue. but I'm not able to understand what I'm doing wrong. same config in jboss eap 6.2, works

Comment: Try with defining it using CLI `/system-property=LOGIN_URL:add(value="https://localhost:8543/test/test.jsp")` and read it using above CLI command.

Comment: I'll be accessing this property from a jsp file within my application. Kinda want this to work with the upgraded version of jboss. cause it works fine in jboss eap 6.2.